# What is $http timeout mean?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, connection, timeout

When using `$http` we can set the timeout for it and it will look something like this:

```
$http.get(url,{timeout: 5000}).success(function(data){});
```

What is that timeout mean? Is it mean the connection (data download) must be completed within the timeout period? Or it is mean the delay time to receive respond from the server? What would be the best general minimal timeout setting for mobile connection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the http request does not complete within the specified `timeout` time, then an error will be triggered.

So, this is kind of like saying the following to the `$http.get()` function:

1. I'd like you to fetch me this URL and get me the data
2. If you do that successfully, then call my `.success()` handler and give me the data.
3. If the request takes longer than 5000ms to finish, then rather than continue to wait, trigger a timeout error.

---

FYI, it looks to me like AngularJS has converted to using standard promise syntax, so you should probably be doing this:

```
$http.get(url,{timeout: 5000}).then(function(data){
    // successfully received the data here
}, function(err) {
    // some sort of error here (could be a timeout error)
});
```

---

> What is that timeout mean? Is it mean the connection (data download) must be completed within the timeout period?

Yes.  If not completed within that time period, it will return an error instead.  This avoids waiting a long time for a request.

> Or it is mean the delay time to receive respond from the server?

No, it is not a delay time.

> What would be the best general minimal timeout setting for mobile connection?

This is hard to say without more specifics.  Lots of different things might drive what you would set this to.  Sometimes, there is no harm in letting the timeout be a fairly long value (say 120 seconds) in case the server or some mobile link happens to be particularly slow some day and you want to give it as much chance as possible to succeed in those circumstances.  In other cases (depending upon the particular user interaction), the user is going to give up anyway if the response time is more than 5 seconds so there may be no value in waiting longer than that for a result the user will have already abandoned.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you mean that the data must fetch complete within 5 sec (based on my example), otherwise it will consider fail? Is that mean if the server does respond within 5 sec, but the data to retrieve is big which will take 30 sec to download. Then that's mean that connection will always consider as fail?

Comment: @user1995781 - How exactly the timeout works when the response itself takes a long time to download is not described in the AngularJS documentation so the only way to know for sure would be to study the AngularJS code and see how it handles the timeout.  It would make sense that the timeout would describe how long it goes with no network activity, not the time for the entire response to download.  But, I honestly don't know and if you want to know, you'd have to either find the implementation of the timeout in the AngularJS code or test it.

Comment: @user1995781 - The best I can tell from looking at the relevant [AngularJS source](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/d077966ff1ac18262f4615ff1a533db24d4432a7/src/ng/httpBackend.js), the timeout is the time for the request to fully complete so it would include any time to download whatever the response is.

Comment: Thanks a lot for checking the source. I have just experiment with it. Truly it required data to download complete. As this is the case, is there anyway I can do the "timeout" for the delay of getting server respond (not data download complete)? You know as on mobile, sometime the connection is not stable, instead of wasting user time waiting on a dead connection, it's better to automatically detect timeout and retry again.

Answer (score 0):

**timeout** *– {number|Promise} –* timeout in milliseconds, or promise that should abort the request when resolved.
[Source](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

Timeout means "perform an action after X time", in JS anyway.